# Is there a way to make a script only run on one game object at a time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project, and I tried to implement a system that allows players into "enter" buildings when they press the E key within a proximity to the building. Basically, when the player presses E next to the entrance of a building, a canvas unique to the building is set to be active. I believed it to be working for a while until I made a second building for the player to interact with. When the E key is pressed now, both canvases for both buildings are displayed and only one can be seen, which is determined by the loading order. I believe the cause for this to be the fact that in order to minimize the number of references I would need to have more buildings; I just made two. One for the building and one for the UI. I assigned the same script to both buildings and assigned the references respectively. Could it be possible that both those references are being assigned to the same variable? Or when the E key is pressed, could the script run on both buildings, resulting in both canvases being set active? I probably did a poor job explaining, I'm pretty new to C# and coding in general. I used two scripts to make the building system, I'll be honest I have no idea why, but I'll attach the one giving me this issue. I know it's rough:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class BuildingScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private GameObject building;
        [SerializeField] private Canvas buildingUI;
        private void enterBuilding(Collider2D other)
        {
            if (BuildingManager.interactable == true)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {

                buildingUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                BuildingManager.canMove = false;

                
                }
            
            }


        }
        private void Update()
        {
            Collider2D collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
            enterBuilding(collider);
            Debug.Log(buildingUI);
        }

        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {


            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
            
                BuildingManager.interactable = true;
            }
            else
            {
            
                BuildingManager.interactable = false;
            }



        }

        private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
        {
        
            BuildingManager.interactable = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: When the user presses E, you write some code to ask the map for the closest building near the player location.

Comment: or uses the building in front of the player and not to the side etc

Comment: Resize your trigger that makes the building interactable, maybe the player is triggering both colliders from the same spot.

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't use a bool flag but set the instance of building (etc) to interact with

For this I would have a general interface like e.g.

```
public interface IInteractable 
{
    void Interact();
}
```

And in you manager script

public class BuildingManager : Monobehavior
{
public static IInteractable interactable;

```
private void Update ()
{
    if (interactable != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        intercatable.Interact();
        canMove = false;     
    }
}
```

and then in your building you don't handle the input but only the interaction like e.g.

```
public class BuildingScript : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject building;
    [SerializeField] private Canvas buildingUI;

    public void Interact()
    {
        buildingUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);         
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        if(BuildingManager.interactable != null) return;
        
        
        BuildingManager.interactable = this;      
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        if(BuildingManager.interactable != this) return;

        BuildingManager.interactable = null;
    }
}
```

---

Personally I wouldn't even let all the buildings handle the collision but rather have the `BuildingManager` on the player object itself and invert the direction of checks and do e.g. directly within `BuildiBuildingManager`

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!other.TryGetComponent<IInteractable>(out var interactable)) return;
    this.interactable = interactable;
}

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (!other.TryGetComponent<IInteractable>(out var interactable)) return;
        if(this.interactable != interactable) return;

        this.interactable = null;
    }
}
```

This way only one central controller handles the user input